# Will my Angular App "break" if the Error is not declared on Observable.Subscribe?

Tags: angular

I'm doing some refactor on my Angular App, and implementing interceptors like a common ErrorHttpInterceptor.

On my tests I noticed
My question is, if I remove the "error" paramater from Subscribe on my observables request it trigger an error. If I let it there, the subscribe error trigger, but apparently my app don't break.

I say apparently cause I'm not being able to properly test if the app breaks or not.

**This is my "test" method:**

```
testAPI(){
    this.myservice.getRequest().subscribe({
        next: data => console.log(data),
        error: error => console.log(error)
    });
}
```

**This is my simplified ErrorInterceptor:**

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        catchError(error => throwError(() => error))
    );

}
```

**I want to know if its ok or reliable to leave my Subscribe like this:**

```
testAPI(){
        this.myservice.getRequest().subscribe({
            next: data => console.log(data)
        });
    }
```

**And trust solenly on ErrorInterceptor to catch and process errors**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your Interceptor to do all your Http Error handling then using Promises and not using subscribe is a cleaner way

Here is a cleaner way of doing it:

Implement your Interceptor like you did but return an EMPTY in your catchError method instead of doing a throw and do a console.error() of the error (you can add the error in a toast as well), because you do not want your app to break everytime an error occurs, you want it to continue.

**In your service making the API request:**

```
async saveAddressDetails(user: User): Promise<any> {
        return await this.http.post<any>(`${this.authURL}update/address`, user).toPromise();
    }
```

**In component where you use the HTTP request:**

```
    const result = await this.auth.saveAddressDetails(this.auth.user);
    
    if (result) {
        this.toast.success('Address Details saved');
    }
```

Notice that if you have an error result will be null and thus the code in the if will not be computed.

Comment: Thanks!! Thats a neat solution :D But about the toPromise(), cause its deprecated I'll use "lastValueFrom" from operator.

Comment: Your server should preferably return the error message you want and then your interceptor can log that error out and you can use a toast for the user and then log out generic error message, e.g. "Internal server error occured"